# Power BI check if today is between end and start date

Tags: powerbi

I am attempting to create a column with 0 or 1 column. I have got IF statement to check if today is between start date and end date.

At the moment, I want it to look at the two dates in one table and assign 1 if today is between start and end dates and 0 if not.

I tried below with no luck

```
Column = IF(AWBPS[START_DTTM] >= today(),1,IF(AWBPS[END_DTTM] <= today (), 0))
```

or

```
Column = DATESBETWEEN(today(), AWBPS[START_DTTM],AWBPS[END_DTTM])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a column with `0` or `1` then it would be the best if you apply your expression in the query editor. So go to `Edit Query > Add Column > Custom Column` and enter the following expression:

```
= if AWBPS[START_DTTM] >= DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) and 
     AWBPS[END_DTTM]   <= DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) 
  then 1 
  else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine conditions in DAX using the `&&` AND operator.

```
Column =
IF ( AWBPS[START_DTTM] >= TODAY () && AWBPS[END_DTTM] <= TODAY (), 1, 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me either, but this did.

```
if DateTime.Date( DateTime.LocalNow() ) >= [DeliveryDate] and DateTime.Date( DateTime.LocalNow() ) <= [Finish] then "True" else "False"
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an older post, but neither of these worked for me.  I filtered the row directly and used an advanced filter.  Set the start date to be before today and the end date to be after today.  Once I clicked OK, I simply replaced the numeric date with `DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())`.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood DAX for Power Query M code.